# Return a value only when all async tasks from a loop are done

Tags: java, firebase

I'm working on a project on android Studio with Firebase.

I have in my project a list of UserID that I want to ''convert'' in UserPseudos. To do this for a single element, I use the following method (which works as I want to) :

```
public interface getPlayerPseudoByUidCallback {
    void onCallbackGetPlayerPseudoByUid(String playerPseudo);
}

public void getPlayerPseudoByUid(String playerUid,getPlayerPseudoByUidCallback callback){
    getAllUsersDatas().whereEqualTo(UID_FIELD,playerUid).get().addOnSuccessListener(queryDocumentSnapshots -> {
        callback.onCallbackGetPlayerPseudoByUid((String) queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments().get(0).get(PSEUDO_FIELD));
    });
}
```

Then, I wrote the following method to do the same for each elements from my list :

```
public interface convertListOfUidInPseudoListener {
    void onCallbackConvertListOfUidInPseudo(List<String> membersPseudos);
}

public void convertListOfUidInPseudo(List<String> membersUid,convertListOfUidInPseudoListener callback){
    AtomicReference<Integer> nbDone = new AtomicReference<>(0);// I use it to know how many tasks are done
    for (int i=0; i<membersUid.size(); i++){
        int finalI = i;// Because variable used in labmda expression should be final
        this.getPlayerPseudoByUid(membersUid.get(i), playerPseudo -> {// The method above
            membersUid.set(finalI,playerPseudo);// I do the ''conversion''
            nbDone.set(nbDone.get() + 1);// A task is done
            System.out.println(playerPseudo);
            if (nbDone.get()==membersUid.size()-1){// I suppose this happen when the current task is the last one
                callback.onCallbackConvertListOfUidInPseudo(membersUid);// I send my result
                System.out.println(membersUid);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**My problem is the following :**

I'm trying to use the AtomicReference ***nbDone*** to check when all my tasks are done, but it still call my callback even if all my list's elements are not ''converted'' ...

Here what I see in Logcat :

*2021-12-05 20:25:10.607 8282-8282/com.example.rtw2 I/System.out: UserPseudo1*

*2021-12-05 20:25:10.607 8282-8282/com.example.rtw2 I/System.out: UserPseudo3*

*2021-12-05 20:25:10.608 8282-8282/com.example.rtw2 I/System.out: [UserPseudo3, 3zSja22AiNegKNFAYdmmX2YiGsz1, UserPseudo1]*

*2021-12-05 20:25:10.609 8282-8282/com.example.rtw2 I/System.out: UserPseudo2*

So as you can see, my callback function is called before all my tasks are done ...

**My question is :**

How to ensure that all asynchronous tasks from my for loop are done before sending the result through my interface ?

--

Thank you for your help,

Don't hesitate to ask for more if needed,

--

**EDIT (12/06/2021):**

Cozimeter helped my by referencing *Class CountDownLatch* which do exactly what I want to do !

I read the documentation and I did the following :

```
    public void convertListOfUidInPseudo(List<String> membersUid, convertListOfUidInPseudoListener callback) {
        CountDownLatch startSignal = new CountDownLatch(1);
        CountDownLatch doneSignal = new CountDownLatch(membersUid.size());

        for (int i=0; i<membersUid.size(); i++){
            new Thread(new Converter(startSignal, doneSignal, membersUid, i)).start();
        }

        try {
            startSignal.countDown();
            System.out.println("startSignal");
            doneSignal.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("All tasks done");
        System.out.println(membersUid);
        callback.onCallbackConvertListOfUidInPseudo(membersUid);
    }

    class Converter implements Runnable {
        private final CountDownLatch startSignal;
        private final CountDownLatch doneSignal;
        public List<String> membersUid;
        public Integer i;

        Converter(CountDownLatch startSignal, CountDownLatch doneSignal,List<String> membersUid, Integer i) {
            this.startSignal = startSignal;
            this.doneSignal = doneSignal;
            this.membersUid = membersUid;
            this.i = i;
        }
        public void run() {
            try {
                startSignal.await();
                doWork();
                doneSignal.countDown();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {} // return;
        }

        void doWork() {
            getPlayerPseudoByUid(membersUid.get(i), playerPseudo -> {
                membersUid.set(i, playerPseudo);
                System.out.println("Conversion of :"+playerPseudo);
                //doneSignal.countDown();// -> Make my app crash ...
            });
//            membersUid.set(i, "UserPseudo");
        }
    }
```

But unfortunately, my logcat send me this :

*startSignal*

*All tasks done*

*[Sr0JUXiycASpo6tnAZR3VYcpcl23, E0m5kJWxRZhVJ7anhboSvIdD15Z2, 3zSja22AiNegKNFAYdmmX2YiGsz1]*

*Conversion of :UserPseudo3*

*Conversion of :UserPseudo*

*Conversion of :UserPseudo2*

I then tried to write *doneSignal.countDown()* inside of my lambda expression in the *doWork()*, but it makes my app crash ...

So my result is still sended before all my tasks are completed.

Comment: If you understand Kotlin, this article will help, [How to read data from Cloud Firestore using get()?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-cloud-firestore-using-get-bf03b6ee4953).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After severals tests, I finally found a solution.
Based on my question 1st script, I did this :

```
public interface convertListOfUidInPseudoListener {
    void onCallbackConvertListOfUidInPseudo(List<String> membersPseudos);
}

public void convertListOfUidInPseudo(List<String> membersUid, convertListOfUidInPseudoListener callback){
    AtomicInteger nbDone = new AtomicInteger (0);
    for (int i=0; i<membersUid.size(); i++){
        int finalI = i;
        this.getPlayerPseudoByUid(membersUid.get(i), playerPseudo -> {
            membersUid.set(finalI,playerPseudo);
            int tasksDone = nbDone.getAndIncrement();// Here is the solution
            System.out.println(playerPseudo);
            System.out.println(tasksDone);

            if (tasksDone==membersUid.size()-1){
                callback.onCallbackConvertListOfUidInPseudo(membersUid);
                System.out.println(membersUid);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

It's the same, but instead of reading directly the AtomicInteger (*nbDone*), I first define an other variable (*tasksDone*) which is equal to *nbDone*. For the moment, I have no problem with this solution.

Here the Logcat :

*2021-12-13 15:57:47.124 23255-23255/com.example.rtw2 I/System.out: UserPseudo2*

*2021-12-13 15:57:47.124 23255-23255/com.example.rtw2 I/System.out: 0*

*2021-12-13 15:57:47.124 23255-23255/com.example.rtw2 I/System.out: UserPseudo1*

*2021-12-13 15:57:47.124 23255-23255/com.example.rtw2 I/System.out: 1*

*2021-12-13 15:57:47.124 23255-23255/com.example.rtw2 I/System.out: UserPseudo3*

*2021-12-13 15:57:47.124 23255-23255/com.example.rtw2 I/System.out: 2*

*2021-12-13 15:57:47.125 23255-23255/com.example.rtw2 I/System.out: [UserPseudo2, UserPseudo1, UserPseudo3]*

I don't exactly know why the script from my question doesn't works and this works, but it works.

(**Just my opinion, but I'm clearly not expert** : As an Atomic variable is defined in multiple threads, I suppose that following it's evolution may be complicated, and so ''freezing'' it's value by defining another variable solve here the problem.)

Answer (score 0):

CountDownLatch may be helpful here.

Comment: Hi Cozimetzer ! Thanks for helping me. This class indeed seems to be what I need. I tried to implement it in my code, but I probably did something wrong. Do you have another clue about how to deal with it ? (I edited my 1st message with what I did)